# How can I get a list of processes without options?

Tags: processes

How can I get a list of processes without options? I know `ps aux | less`
works, but it still shows command line options. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can control `ps`'s output in detail using the `-o` option, which selects the specific columns you're interested in. Thus

```
ps -e -o pid,user,comm
```

will show for every process in the system (`-e`, equivalent to your `ax`), the process's id, user and command (without arguments).

You can read about the various options in the [`ps` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html).

```
ps -e -o comm
```

In your case, you should use this which exclusively gets the process name.

Comment: You're welcome! If this worked for you, please accept the answer using the big checkmark, that will signal that your question has been answered (and give you and me reputation points).

Answer (score -1):

Try this to get the list of processes on red-hat: -o defines the output format

```
ps -eo cmd
```

For more refer man page of `ps`.

On solaris try : -o defines the output format

```
ps -e -o fname
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this still outputs with command line options.

Comment: The `ps -eo cmd` works fine for me on red-hat , and what does command line options mean and which OS are you using ?

Comment: That's not the issue. The command works fine, but it does not do what I want it to do.

Comment: `ps -eo cmd` shows the full command line (`ps -eo cmd`), the OP only wants to see the command (`ps`).

Comment: Well as per your question , you needed list of processes right and the command gives all the list of the processes in the memory, so I couldn't what was the issue ?

Comment: @StephenKitt,  From the query 'list of processes' I understood that the need was to print the list of processes but not just the command.

Comment: There's no need to argue about this, you didn't give me what I needed, the results that were requested were already obtained. Please don't start an argument.

Comment: I was just trying to understand what was wrong with the answer , @StephenKitt helped me with that. Thanks for that.

Comment: Ah okay! As long as you guys don't wish to argue about it.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this approximation by parsing ps output with `basename`:

```
for i in $(ps -fea | awk '{print $8}'); do basename $i; done | sort -u
```